# Removing Link amplifier after links have established

Tags: ingress

Normal portal link range of a portal to establish link to another one is not sufficient. After placing 4 (or less) link amplifiers and establish links and fields, if I remove the link amp(s) to replace them with some other modules will the links and fields be broken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long links and fields will remain even after the Link Amp mod is destroyed. **However**,  as of August 28th, it is not possible to remove portal mods, unless the mod is destroyed by an attack! Hence - the Link Amp mods can't be removed and changed to a different (i.e Portal Shield) mod until attacked by the enemy.

(Source: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+Ingress/posts/LVTdiXNBvNv )

Comment: I guess my timing for asking the question is quite good. It was possible but now it is not :D

Comment: yeah. I was actually waiting before answering because I wanted to supply screenshots demonstrating it, but waited too long. :-)

Answer (score 6):

No, links and fields will remain.

What you describe is a good strategy for making mega fields more resistant to attack :D. 
Once the field is done, replace link amp with very rare shields and your portal will be much more difficult to destroy (unless of use of virus :( )

**EDIT (28/08/2013)** : As described by @idan315, there was an update yesterday that limit mod placing. Only 1 mod per portal per player, and no more removal allowed...

The strategy explained before will no longer be possible.

Comment: Now it is 2 mods per portal per player.